# Extjs TextField with a store

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I want to expand a TextField in a custom control, so that it can hold two fields of my model (an id field and a description field), just like a combo, but in TextField (or TriggerField).

I need too, that when I post a form, the id property be send to server.

Firstly I thing to create a store in this control, but I want to hear more ideas.

thanks.

Comment: Description is not enough. What you gonna display in your field?

Comment: Just like combobox, I want to display the "description" field.

Comment: So, if you gonna made something like combobox, maybe you should extend it?

Comment: I do prefer TriggerField, because I need two or more buttons on it.

Comment: I think, if your gonna work with record set you can use the store, else you don't need it.

Comment: hum.. So how to configure the control in a way that it bind automatically the two fields ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend a combobox with as much buttons as you like. It is quite easy:

provide the CLS

```
trigger2Cls: 'x-form-clear-trigger'
```

Note that the number must increment the more buttons you need

Now ExtJS will look for a Trigger handler

```
onTrigger2Click: function(args){}
```

That's it. You don't need a new Component for that.

Comment: Hi sra, I cant believe combobox also had this property.. Thanks!

Comment: @paulo Yeah. Somethings it's a bit hard to find it all. In this I found it while digging through the sourcecode

Answer (score 0):

Field can't contain two another fields. As you know field contains value.
Display value (**raw value** in Ext terminology) and submitted value (value) may be different.

Direct and reverse convert makes rawToValue and valueToRaw.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-method-rawToValue